# Encrypt decrypt using mcrypt and sha-512?

Tags: php

I have gotten a code from php.net. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Problem is when you encrypt something, the next time the ecrypted one isn't the same as the first one. I need to get the exact same hash using sha512 or sha256. I also need to decrypt it because the function will be used for encrypting customer's name and other data.

Thanks  in advance!

Comment: SHA-512 is a one-way hashing function, and is theoretically impossible to decrypt. Also, there's nothing bad, with the same input producing a different encrypted output (in fact, that's usually more secure). As long as you get back the original input, that's not a problem

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do. Do you want to compare a new input with an existing encrypted value? → decrypt and compare. Or you might store a hash value in addition to the encrypted value, then you can hash the new input and compare it with the stored hash.

Comment: As @knittl says you _don't_ decrypt something that has been encrypted using a one-way hashing function.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Because you don't _encrypt_ anything with a hashing function! You _hash_ something.

Comment: Obviously, but the OP hasn't specified what he's doing.

Comment: There are a ton of encrypt/decrypt examples within the comments @ php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: Theoretically, I think there should be a way to get the same hash value because how can you perform a search of the names or customer or a product if you can't get the hash function. If you will unhash everything, then compare you'd exeed the 30s execution time..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Comment: The user input is hashed with the same algorithm before it is compared with database values

Comment: @EarvinBryanS.Co: A hashing function is deterministic, for a hash (not for encryption), you will always get the same output for the same input. But you cannot "reverse" the hash, it's a one-way function. If you need to get the original data, you have to use encryption. That might produce a totally different output every time – **but** you will be able decrypt it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting / Decrypting file with Mcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/encrypting-decrypting-file-with-mcrypt). See John Conde's answer. It provides a generic routine to encrypt and decrypt (not tied to a file).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mcrypt for hashing, consider using the [`hash()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) instead.

Remember, hashes is one-way methods and cannot be 'decrypted'.

Looking for encryption/decryption I would recommend you look at AES encryption - either through MySQL if you have your data stored in the database, otherwise `mcrypt()` can also manage AES.

Comment: It is not true, it can be decrypted if not used with salt. https://crackstation.net/

Comment: @JohnMax, it's not "decryption". It's just matching identical hashes by looking them up in rainbow tables.

Answer (score 0):

I shared my crypt wrapper at https://stackoverflow.com/a/173764/17404. Try using that.