# Retrieve a php value and use it in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

In my website I set some values to session object like "user_status", "user_name" and like so. The php file looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var logged = <? echo $this->session->getValueOf("user_status"); ?>;
</script>

<a class="show_message" href="#">SHow my status</a>
```

Well, I have a js script that pretends do an action according to `user status` in the website, so, I have this:

```
$('.show_status').click(function(event){

    //ask for user status
    if (logged){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        //do another action for visitors
    }
});
```

Walking around I thought if it is the best way flow data between `session` -> `javascript`, because if you inspect the page source at browser the value of `user_status` will be visible and could be riskable for website security.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

1. `logged` var only takes a boolean value.
2. The js action must be executed each time the element `#(".show_status")` is clicked.

Comment: *Walking around I have thong* - Best ever.

Comment: Really, if simply reading a (logged-in) user's status is a high-almighty security threat, *damn dawg, **you got problems***.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think you need to walk around and thong for a bit longer.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson - Some things just beat all. LOL

Comment: sorry, be tolerant cause it is not my native language LOL

Comment: No worries Manix. I kid.

Comment: @manix there is *nothing* wrong with your English, had you not told us just now we wouldn't have guessed you're not a native speaker. I thought it was a typo.

Comment: @manix, there is no shame in having a few grammar/spelling mistakes if English isn't your native tongue.  A bit of advice for the future though is that you may wish to state that in your question to reduce the amount of joking you get from other people.

Comment: @MichaelFenwick - I was actually thinking iOS completion bologne, but hey, I get your point. I didn't really think the OP was ESL, but he seems to have humor, which helps regardless. `:)`

Comment: Hahaha, no problem! I took this moment so funny, you are welcome :D

Comment: @manix, you're awesome. I wish more SO users had your humor. `:)` I don't mean that lightly, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JavaScript is just being used for interface stuff, and doesn't have any back end effects, I probably wouldn't worry too much about the insecurity of handling that logic client-side.

If security is an important thing though, I would recommend you use PHP to write the appropriate JavaScript function.  For example:

On the page being viewed, perhaps in the header, you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    if ($this->session->getValueOf("user_status")) {
        require_once('logged_in_user_functions.js');
    } else {
        require_once('visitor_functions.js');
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

In the file `logged_in_user_functions.js' you have:

```
function showComment(id) {
    //logic that shows the comment here
}

function showCommentSubmissionForm() {
    //logic that adds this form to the page goes here
}
```

Meanwhile, in the file `visitor_functions.js' you have:

```
function showComment(id) {
    //logic that shows the comment in a different way goes here
}

function showCommentSubmissionForm() {
    //logic to display a message saying the user needs to log in to post a comment goes here
}
```

Then you can add your logic into your page without having to check the user status.  The proper behaviour is provided by virtue of which .js file was included:

```
<button id='add_comment_button' onclick='showCommentSubmissionForm()'>Add Comment</button>
```

This gives PHP (and thus the server, not the client) final say in what gets displayed to the user.

Comment: I wouldn't advice inline code execution just to achieve a restricted action. In short, JavaScript should not be doing any private-access related type stuff in the first place. You can manipulate a UI via JavaScript console but at the end of the day, the server is the enforcer of data I/O. In this case, I'd set a constant or define a config.

Comment: Hmmm, I like this method, the only "negative" part is that my php markup becomes so chaotic

Comment: @manix, Chaotic how?  Do you mean that the opening and closing php tags just look ugly?  I can't disagree there, but functionally it's not all that bad.  One thing that you can do to help clean in up is to use the same code outline to import (using `require_once`) the appropriate JavaScript functions.  This would keep the whole logic in a single set of `<?php ?>` tags and could import the appropriate version of multiple JavaScript functions as needed.

Comment: @MichaelFenwick, brilliant idea, but what happened after the php is procesed? The js action will be displayed once time. It should be lauched in every `.show_message` click

Comment: @manix, the idea is to write two versions of the JavaScript function that define the proper behaviour in each case.  I'll edit my answer to explain in a little more detail what I mean.

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much, and the rest of people too. PS: I did not know that `require_once` could include js files!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `user_status` will be something like `Active`, then this isn't really a security risk.

If you want to hide *everything* from casualy prying eyes, you could try using an encrypted cookie, using something like [How to save encrypted data in cookie (using php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173764/187954) to encrypt your values.

Comment: yes, `user_status` only can takes the value of `1` or `0`, and the cookie is actually encrypted